# Lot of errors after upgrading stylelint to 14.0.0

Tags: config, prettier, stylelint

I was upgrading stylelint to V14 according to this [this migration guide](https://stylelint.io/migration-guide/to-14).So I ran `stylelint-config-standard-scss` and have also added to stylelint config file. Since we are also using stylelint-prettier at the same time, so now the config file looks like this (there was never any other rules):

```
{
  "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard-scss","stylelint-prettier/recommended"]
}
```

However, when i run `npm run stylelint` i got many errors (which didn't exist before package updating):

```
modules/.../_style.scss
   1:1   ✖  Expected mixin name to be kebab-case                                                                 scss/at-mixin-pattern        
   3:3   ✖  Expected empty line before rule                                                                      rule-empty-line-before       
   6:14  ✖  Expected "0.75" to be "75%"                                                                          alpha-value-notation         
   8:3   ✖  Expected empty line before rule                                                                      rule-empty-line-before       
  27:3   ✖  Expected empty line before rule                                                                      rule-empty-line-before       
  32:3   ✖  Expected empty line before rule                                                                      rule-empty-line-before       
  37:3   ✖  Expected empty line before rule                                                                      rule-empty-line-before       
  40:3   ✖  Expected empty line before rule                                                                      rule-empty-line-before       
  50:3   ✖  Expected empty line before rule                                                                      rule-empty-line-before       
  51:14  ✖  Expected "0.8" to be "80%"                                                                           alpha-value-notation         
  53:3   ✖  Expected empty line before rule                                                                      rule-empty-line-before       
  55:14  ✖  Expected "1" to be "100%"                                                                            alpha-value-notation       
....
```

I guess it's because i didn't configure it correctly. But the thing i don't understand it why there were no rules before and now it seems i'd need to configure so many now. Are they added to the new version V14? Or is it a conflict between prettier and the new stylelint version?

Since i am pretty new to updating packages, my apologies if my question doesn't make so much sense. Any inputs are welcome! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You configured it correctly.

The `stylelint-config-standard-scss` package is separate from the `stylelint` one and has its [own CHANGELOG](https://github.com/stylelint-scss/stylelint-config-standard-scss/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md). Version 2.0.0 of the package [turned on a dozen new rules](https://github.com/stylelint-scss/stylelint-config-standard-scss/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#200). Additionally, the package updated the two shared configs it extends which, in turn, have their own CHANGELOGs:

- [stylelint-config-standard](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-standard/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#2300)
- [stylelint-config-recommended-scss](https://github.com/stylelint-scss/stylelint-config-recommended-scss/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500)

Both of these configs turned on new rules in their last major releases.

In summary, by updating to version 2.0.0 of `stylelint-config-standard-scss` over two dozen new rules were turned on.

Ideally, you should update your codebase to fix the problems. Alternatively, you can [extend the config](https://github.com/stylelint-scss/stylelint-config-standard-scss#extending-the-config) and turn off any rules you don't want.

For example, to turn off the `alpha-value-notation` rule:

```
{
  "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard-scss","stylelint-prettier/recommended"],
  "rules": {
    "alpha-value-notation": null
  }
}
```

Comment: No worries. Please mark the question as answered if my explanation addresses the question.